# "App\Entity\Products" object not found by "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ArgumentResolver\EntityValueResolver"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, entity

I keep getting this error in symfony 6 and I dont know what I'm doing wrong, my code seems correct to me. Symfony's argument resolver system is unable to find an instance of the "Products" entity I keep getting this error when I try to inject an instance of the entity class product into a controller parameters, but it cannot find it.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Products;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

#[Route('/produits', name: 'products_')]
class ProductsController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/', name: 'index')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('products/index.html.twig');
    }

    #[Route('/{slug}', name: 'details')]
    public function details(Products $user): Response
    {
        dd($user);
        return $this->render('products/details.html.twig');
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Entity\trait\CreatedAtTrait;
use App\Entity\trait\SlugTrait;
use App\Repository\ProductsRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ProductsRepository::class)]

class Products
{
    use CreatedAtTrait;
    use SlugTrait;

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]
    private ?string $description = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $price = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $stock = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'Products')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?Categories $categories = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'Products', targetEntity: Images::class, orphanRemoval: true)]
    private Collection $images;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'Products', targetEntity: OrdersDetails::class)]
    private Collection $ordersDetails;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->images = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->ordersDetails = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->created_at = new \DateTimeImmutable();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): static
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): static
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrice(): ?int
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    public function setPrice(int $price): static
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStock(): ?int
    {
        return $this->stock;
    }

    public function setStock(int $stock): static
    {
        $this->stock = $stock;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCategories(): ?Categories
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }

    public function setCategories(?Categories $categories): static
    {
        $this->categories = $categories;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Images>
     */
    public function getImages(): Collection
    {
        return $this->images;
    }

    public function addImage(Images $image): static
    {
        if (!$this->images->contains($image)) {
            $this->images->add($image);
            $image->setProducts($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeImage(Images $image): static
    {
        if ($this->images->removeElement($image)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($image->getProducts() === $this) {
                $image->setProducts(null);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, OrdersDetails>
     */
    public function getOrdersDetails(): Collection
    {
        return $this->ordersDetails;
    }

    public function addOrdersDetail(OrdersDetails $ordersDetail): static
    {
        if (!$this->ordersDetails->contains($ordersDetail)) {
            $this->ordersDetails->add($ordersDetail);
            $ordersDetail->setProducts($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeOrdersDetail(OrdersDetails $ordersDetail): static
    {
        if ($this->ordersDetails->removeElement($ordersDetail)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($ordersDetail->getProducts() === $this) {
                $ordersDetail->setProducts(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the file that describes the `App\Entity\Products` class saved?

Comment: its saved src/Entity

Comment: @Rachel109 is App\Entity defined in your service.yaml so that the entities can be added to service containers?

Comment: Do you mean this line `    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'`

Comment: @Rachel109 I would remove it from the exclude, clear the cache and try again. In my opinion, the entities in this case must be known to the service container.

Comment: thanks clearing the cache seems to have made it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product $user is not working if it is not the primary key. If you don't want the use the primary key then you need to use MapEntity / ParamConverter for this.

This example is for Symfony 6.2+. Otherwise, check the ParamConverter from the SensioFrameworkBundle.

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Attribute\MapEntity;

#[Route('/{slug}', name: 'details')]
public function details(
    #[MapEntity(mapping: ['slug' => 'name'])] Products $product
): Response
{
    dd($product);
    return $this->render('products/details.html.twig');
}
```

I don't see "slug" in your entity. I used "name" as an example.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible not exist in your database the 'id' of this product. And it's important you atendant the response of @jpvdw if you don't use the 'id' with the injection dependency.

see: [value_resolver](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/value_resolver.html)