# "App\Entity\Groups" object not found by "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ArgumentResolver\EntityValueResolver"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a Repository function that gets called via AJAX that updates a field in the database that throws the error ""App\Entity\Groups" object not found by "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ArgumentResolver\EntityValueResolver"."

I have incorporated the suggestion and answer from ["App\Entity\Products" object not found by "Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ArgumentResolver\EntityValueResolver"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77127121/app-entity-products-object-not-found-by-symfony-bridge-doctrine-argumentresol) and still get the error. I am using Symfony 6.3 and PHP 8.2.

Comment: Will the other entities be found?

Comment: No, they aren't

Comment: You will find an answer - see your link - from me that was probably also the solution. -->> "@Rachel109 I would remove it from the exclude, clear the cache and try again. In my opinion, the entities in this case must be known to the service container."

Comment: Already did that with no success... I removed the entity line from the excludes and cleared my cache...

Comment: I am using laragon for my local dev environment... would that have anything to do with it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Laragon. The entities cannot be resolved. Is the namespace correct? Please pay attention to the spelling of the folder structure (upper/lower case) and namespaces.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255666/discussion-between-manzwebdesigns-and-bademeister).